# Typescript Sum Pluck Type

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a sumPluck function. It will allow the caller to specify a property of type number belonging to an object in an array then sum them.

Example:

```js
type A = { prop: number }

const arr: A[] = [{prop: 1}, {prop: 2}];

pluckSum("prop", arr); // 3
```

I know how to type a pluck but I can't seem to get my type to recognize that it is actually only dealing with number properties.  This is what I have:

```js
type PropertiesOfTypeNames<T, U> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never }[keyof T];
    type PropertiesOfType<T, U> = Pick<T, PropertiesOfTypeNames<T, U>>;

    type NumberProperties<T> = PropertiesOfType<T, number>;

    const pluckSum = <T, K extends keyof NumberProperties<T>>(arr: T[], k: K) =>
        pipe(
            arr,
            R.map(v => v[k]),
            R.sum
        );
```

I get an error under the map saying : Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'number

So it doesn't seem that the mapped type communicates that v[k] is a number property. I must be doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I just needed to add Record like this:

```js
const pluckSum = <T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof NumberProperties<T>>(arr: T[], k: K) =>
    pipe(
        arr,
        R.map(v => v[k]),
        R.sum
    );
```

**Update 1**
I guess I can further refine it by removing the mapped type "NumberProperties" since Record takes care of what I was trying to achieve anyways. So the final version is just:

```js
const pluckSum = <T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof T>(k: K, arr: T[]) =>
    pipe(
        arr,
        R.map(v => v[k]),
        R.sum
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of Typescript I wanted to show you an alternative approach with loop fusion, i.e. elimination of the redundant array traversal. I gain loop fusion with a somewhat unorthodox combinator of type `(b -> c) -> (a -> c -> d) -> a -> b -> d` (in Hindley-Milner notation), which I call `contramap2nd`, because it contra-maps on the second argument of a binary function.

Long story, short story:

```js
// (b -> c) -> (a -> c -> d) -> a -> b -> d
const contramap2nd = g => f => x => y =>
  f(x) (g(y));

const arrFold = f => init => xs =>
  xs.reduce((acc, x) => f(acc) (x), init);
  
const add = x => y => x + y;
const prop = k => o => o[k];

const pluckSum = k =>
  arrFold(
    contramap2nd(
      prop(k))
        (add)) (0);

console.log(
  pluckSum("foo") ([{foo: 1}, {foo: 2}, {foo: 3}]));
```

You can do the contra-mapping on the second argument of `add` by hand, of course, if you don't like `contramap2nd`.

Please note that you can gain loop fusion with both `map`, `contramap` et al.